# What the cost of renting an apartment in Republic of Ireland (Dublin)?

Tags: students, rental, ireland

I'm a non-EU citizen. I want to move to Ireland this September. I want to know what is the cost of an apartment for a student in Dublin - really need something affordable.
Any recommendations, tips, or connections will be needed.

Comment: What research have you done up to now? What is ‘affordable’?